# Making some code only run once

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have some code that I would like to run only once in my MainViewController. It should run every time the user starts the app, but only after the MainViewController has loaded.

I don't want to run it in `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application`.

Here's the idea I had:

MainViewController.h

```
@interface IpadMainViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {
    BOOL hasRun;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasRun;
```

MainViewController.m

```
@synthesize hasRun;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (hasRun == 0) {
        // Do some stuff
        hasRun = 1;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats wrong with running `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` or your code? Or if you don't alloc your MainViewCOntroller, it would be run once anyways

Comment: Once per _activation_ (i.e., once at launch and again when it returns from the background), or once per time it gets loaded into memory?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Swift 1,2:**

```
static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

dispatch_once(&token) {
  NSLog("Do it once")
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
  NSLog(@"Do it once");
});
```

**Swift 3,4:**

> dispatch_once is no longer available in Swift. In Swift, you can use
>   lazily initialized globals or static properties and get the same
>   thread-safety and called-once guarantees as dispatch_once provided
>   [Apple doc](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/)

```
let myGlobal = { … global contains initialization in a call to a closure … }()
_ = myGlobal  // using myGlobal will invoke 
              // the initialization code only the first time it is used.
```

Comment: +1; GCD is a cleaner choice for this task than maintaining a BOOL state in your class

Comment: Note that this is once per the app being loaded into memory. The code will not be run again for another instance of this class being created (this bit me recently), nor will it be run again when the app returns to the foreground from suspension.

Comment: Great answer. This feels much more elegant than my original idea. I've learned something. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good point, do you know anyway to "reset" the GCD or instance of the class so that this can be called again at some point? Could I call `[[ClassName alloc] init];` to "reset" it?

Comment: It's possible to reset the `once` token, @RazorSharp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930044/possible-to-reset-state-of-dispatch-once-in-unit-test-to-make-them-run-again/10938057#10938057, although at that point I'd say you should just use another mechanism that's _supposed_ to be reset, like Dylan's suggestion for a `BOOL` property.

Comment: I use this so often, yet I still end up coming back to this answer.

Comment: I knew about this, I just came here for the code snippet

Comment: use __block  with variable name if you want to change the value of variable.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any problem with that code.  I like using a BOOL (as you did) and then assigning either YES/NO or TRUE/FALSE just so that the code reads more nicely.  I would assign TRUE to firstRun in didFinishLaunching, and set it FALSE after the code executes. In my code these type of conditionals usually look like this:

```
@synthesize firstRun;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    if (firstRun) {
        // code to run only once goes here
        firstRun = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The other answer which recommends Grand Central Dispatch is arguably a better approach.  On the other hand, as a BSD-level technology it has a reasonably steep learning curve considering that this is a "basic" question. If you want to do what you've asked, this code is slightly cleaner than your original- if you want to try a more advanced approach to task management GCD is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Possible variation (Swift 5):

```
// Whether this is the first code run since app (re)started
var firstRun: Bool = true

public final class Foo {
    public init() {
        if firstRun {
            // Code that has to be run only once goes
            // HERE
            firstRun = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no dispatch_once_t ins **swift 3** and above, we can use **lazy initialized global variables**.

Make a lazy global variable

```
lazy var doOnlyOnce: () -> Void = {
    .. add code to run only once here ..
    return {}
}()
```

To run the code:

```
_ = doOnlyOnce
```

Answer (score -2):

With Swift2.0, Xcode 7.0

```
var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super. viewDidLoad()
    dispatch_once(&token) {
        println("This is printed only on the first call to test()")
    }
    println("This is printed for each call to test()")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

for Swift2.2,Xcode 7.3:

```
static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

dispatch_once(&YourClassName.token) {
  NSLog("Do it once")
}
```

Watch out "`YourClassName.token`"