# Possible to reset state of dispatch_once in unit test, to make them run again

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Is it possible to reset the state of dispatch_once code in a unit test tearDown?

I think it would be nice if our unit tests could run from a really clean state, but we are struggling with dispatch_once and some singletons made with dispatch once.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I should note first that this isn't a good thing to do in any situation other than testing; even then, proceed with care -- AliSoftware provides some details and example code in comments below. See also the interesting answers at [Can I declare a `dispatch_once_t` predicate as a member variable instead of static?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13856037), including some important information [from the horse's mouth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19845164/).

`dispatch_once_t` is a `typedef`d `long`. Its false value is 0. If you reset that flag to 0, `dispatch_once()` will run again. Your problem is "just" how to change the value of a static variable from another compilation unit. For this, I think you need a debug/unit test hook, like so:

MakeWhoopie.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void makeWhoopie(void);

#ifdef DEBUG
void resetDispatchOnce(void);
#endif
```

MakeWhoopie.m

```
#include "MakeWhoopie.h"

static dispatch_once_t * once_token_debug;

void makeWhoopie(void)
{

    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    once_token_debug = &once_token;    // Store address of once_token
                                       // to access it in debug function.
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        NSLog(@"That's what you get, folks.");
    });

    NSLog(@"Making whoopie.");
}

#ifdef DEBUG
void resetDispatchOnce(void)
{
    *once_token_debug = 0;
}
#endif
```

(You could also move `once_token` up to file level and change it directly.)

Trying this out:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MakeWhoopie.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        makeWhoopie();
        makeWhoopie();
        resetDispatchOnce();
        makeWhoopie();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

> 2012-06-07 18:45:28.134 ResetDispatchOnce[8628:403] That's what you get, folks.
>   2012-06-07 18:45:28.163 ResetDispatchOnce[8628:403] Making whoopie.
>   2012-06-07 18:45:28.164 ResetDispatchOnce[8628:403] Making whoopie.
>   2012-06-07 18:45:28.165 ResetDispatchOnce[8628:403] That's what you get, folks.
>   2012-06-07 18:45:28.165 ResetDispatchOnce[8628:403] Making whoopie.

Comment: The point of `dispatch_once` is that it is thread-safe. The problem by setting `*once_token_debug = 0` this way is that it's not thread-safe at all in cases another thread uses `dispatch_once(&onceToken, …)`  while you set the `onceToken` by yourself. How come we can prevent such issue?

Comment: @AliSoftware: The scenario in the question is unit testing, and that's the _only_ use I propose for this procedure. The token is being reset _between_ tests, to create a clean slate just as would be created between runs of the larger program. Threading is not an issue because the program is not running between tests.

Comment: I understood this, but everybody have to be aware of that and not being tempted to use this in a non-threadsafe manner elsewhere. And there may be some cases even in Unit Tests that this is not thread-safe, especially if one badly codes its test and does asynchronous actions that continue running even after the tests ends (like a call to `dispatch_after(10s, ^{ /* sthg that uses sharedInstance */ }` if the test reaches its timeout it will fail and be stopped and reach `tearDown` but the block using sharedInstance will still be dispatched in a near future… after the tearDown.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/AliSoftware/6935128 for an example where some long async code (that may still run even after your test did `tearDown`) can create a potential risk.

Of course I agree that (1) this is quite unlikely and (2) this is bad programming, the user should fix its Unit Test to check if the test timed out at the time the completion block is called. But newbies can still run into such tricky cases, so IMHO it's worth a warning for users not used to concurrency subtleties, to let them know that this is to be used with caution and only in specific cases.

Comment: Fair enough, @AliSoftware; thanks for your concern and the example. I've added a warning to the post.

Answer (score 4):

We too unit test our singletons and occasionally need to replace them with mock objects or reset them. I took Josh's answer and simplified it a bit further:

```
static ArticleManager *_sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t once_token = 0;

+(ArticleManager *)sharedInstance {
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        if (_sharedInstance == nil) {
            _sharedInstance = [[ArticleManager alloc] init];
        }
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

+(void)setSharedInstance:(ArticleManager *)instance {
    if (instance == nil) once_token = 0;
    _sharedInstance = instance;
}
```

Comment: I wrote a blog post explaining why you should do it this way: http://twobitlabs.com/2013/01/objective-c-singleton-pattern-unit-testing/

Comment: I mentioned putting the once token at file level in my answer. Note that use of my -- or anyone's -- code posted on SO, whether verbatim or modified, [requires](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that you include [attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). In this case the mechanism is so straightforward that it's hardly worth a mention, but please don't get into the habit of blogging based on SO answers without at least linking back.

Comment: Actually, the == nil check inside the dispatch_once seems redundant.  You only reset the once_token if _sharedInstance was set nil.

Comment: Yep, you are correct, I could remove the nil check in setSharedInstance and it would still work fine.