# Naming private methods that return a property value

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, structure

Below is a code example that is causing me some pain and wondered if anyone could help.  I want to set the class 'version' property within the constructor since it uses up a lot of processing (so dont want to re-calculate it every time another class gets the property).

If I name the method (not exposed to other classes) correctly, I would call it `- (NSString *)version` rather than `getVersion`.  However, then it would become the getter for this class.

So my question is, the code below contains a method that wrongly uses the term 'get' as a prefix, but if I remove the get, then suddenly the internal method becomes a public getter, which I don't want it to be.

Does anyone know the best practice to avoid this?

```
#pragma mark Constructor

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here
        self.version = [self getVersion];
    }    
    return self;
}

#pragma mark General

- (NSString *)getVersion
{
   // some computation to work out version
}
```

Comment: `[self computedVersion]`?

Comment: Is `version` a public property?

Comment: I think that if you call `permformSelector:@selector(getVersion)` the method will get called anyway...

Comment: You shall not start method name with `get` in obj-c if the method doesn't have a return parameter!

Comment: MYPREFIX_version for private variant seems good to me.. e.g. DD_version

Comment: there are no private/public methods in objC -- just methods

Comment: @nhgrif: yes - version is a public property

Comment: @Sulthan - I think apple would say you shalt not start with the prefix 'get' even if its does return a value ;-)

Comment: @CharlieSeligman See the difference between returning a value and having a return parameter (e.g. `-[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)version {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_version == nil) {
            // some computation to work out version
            _version = //result of computation
        }
    }
    return _version;
}
```

The first time you call `[self version]` (in the `init`), `retVersion` is `nil`, so the computation is performed.  Each time after that, it's non-nil and is static, so you just return the result of the first computation.

And if need be, you can change `_version` from other methods (outside this getter).

Comment: PS: You can also use the internal property variable _version rather than relying on a separate static var.

Comment: @Francesco: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856037/can-i-declare-dispatch-once-t-predicate-as-a-member-variable-instead-of-static is a long discussion about whether dispatch_once can be used with *instance* variables or not.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the link… I read it.. but still I did not understand if it is possible or not. The Apple header does not say that we cannot use in an instance variable, but that the token must be zero before calling dispatch_once… What if you set to zero the token in the constructor and use the dispatch token to initialize (lazily) a variable? In my test class works.. but maybe the example is too simple to see if there are problems...

Comment: @Francesco: The Apple docs say that the predicate must be in global or static scope, which means that it *cannot* be an instance variable. - But most people in that discussion seem to think that it *should work* or *does work*. - The implementation of GCD is quite complicated because it has to handle e.g. multi-threading and multi-processors. So there may be more reasons for this restriction than just the initialisation to zero. - I do not know the answer.

Comment: @Francesco: Another discussion is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19835392/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Ok.. I was confused by the comment in the header near the dispatch_once_t typedef definition… the doc explicitly says the token must be in the global/static scope.. so.. even if it works it is better not to use it in the instance variable… btw I used it only for singleton…

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default getter in a way that it performs the computation only once.
This way you won't need to make the assignment in the constructor.

```
- (NSString *)version
{
    // check if internal variable has data, if not, do your thing
    if (!_version) {
        // perform your intensive version fetching operation 
        // and assign it to the internal variable of the property _version
        _version = [self versionImplementation];
    }
    // now just return it
    return _version;
}
```

Internal variables are helpful for setters too, for example in validating data

```
- (void)setVersion:(NSString *)newVersion
{
    if( newVersion > kSomeConstant )
    {
        _version = newVersion;
    }
}
```

When a property is synthesised, _version is created automatically so you can be sure that it exists. You can also customise what the internal variable name is by explicitly synthesising it

```
@synthesize version = _myCustomVersionVariable;
```

Comment: Use underscore as a prefix not a suffix for ivar names. Not following the convention breaks KVC compatibility, among other things.

Comment: @jlehr Its against convention but its an example of customisation

Comment: So why provide an example that violates Apple's documented naming convention for ivars in a way that may lead to problems? Also, your setter method is misnamed -- it should be `setVersion:`, not `version:`. Please update your answer.