# NSClassFromString misbehaving and caching class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I have a class `X` and several classes `X1,X2,X3,X4` that are descendants of `X`

I have a `NSArray` with the name of the classes and I'm using it to iterate:

```
_classnames = @[@"X1",@"X2",@"X3",@"X4"];
```

And then:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString * identifier = @"cellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier 
                                   forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    X * xshared = [NSClassFromString(_classnames[indexPath.row]) shared];
    cell.textLabel.text = [xshared title];
    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Funny thing is:

```
for (NSString * s in _classnames) {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSClassFromString(s));
}
```

works outside the `tableView` call

But then all `NSClassFromString` return the class `X1`

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you just print the value of the `NSClassFromString` response, is it the class you expect? Maybe your `shared` method is returning the wrong value.

Comment: No I have `NSLog`'ed the response. It always return X1

Comment: Why is it always return X1, I just don't understand.

Comment: can you provide some info about "shared" method? did you try after changing the order of items in _classnames array?

Comment: I actually solved it. The problem indeed was in the inheritance of `shared` method. The answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error and I'm posting here just for the sake of completion.

In class `X` I was declaring `shared` as

```
+ (instancetype)shared {
    static id _shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _shared = [self new];
    });

    return _shared;
}
```

And I was not implementing `shared` in the child classes.

Adding `shared` to the child classes solved the problem. The reason it returns always the first class instantiated is pretty obvious but I didn't see.

Comment: Wow, that's a fun bug. You might be interested in [Using dispatch_once_t per object and not per class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19832150)