# Lazy loading Objective-C class with int properties

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, int, null

I use the following as a getter for a property in one of my classes:

```
- (NSString *)version
{
    if (_version == nil) {
        _version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    }
    return _version;
}
```

This works well.  However, when I try the same for an int property I obviously get an error since int are never nil.  What is the best way around this?

```
- (int)numberOfDays
{
    if (_numberOfDays == nil) {
        // relatively memory intense calculation that works out numberOfDays:
        _numberOfDays = X;
    }    
    return _numberOfDays;
}
```

Comment: Either use a value that you know cannot occur (maybe -1?), or more clearly, just have a BOOL field (e.g. `_numberOfDaysComputed`).

Comment: `dispatch_once(&token, ^{ hard_computation(); });`

Comment: @H2CO3: That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, using `int` is not recommended Objective-C if possible. If you need to use a primitive integer type, you should use `NSInteger`. The size of NSInteger is determined at compile time based on the architecture(s) being built for. `int` is a static size that will not widen for different architectures. It's OK to use it, just be aware.

Using NSInteger, you still face the same problem, it can't be nil. You should therefore make your property an `NSNumber` which you can init with the result of your computation with `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:anInteger];`. That way, you can keep you nil check on your property and only do the computation once to create your `NSNumber`.

Comment: Why should not be `int` used in Objective-C?

Comment: I just explained that. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int

Comment: "It has a different size on different architectures" is not an explanation, since that's true for `int` as well. Also, the answer you linked to is disagreed with by quite a few people.

Comment: @H2CO3, just as a note: `int` does not change size on any of the platforms we're talking about. It's always 32-bit. It *could* be different, but it never is within the Apple world, and it almost certainly never will be.

Comment: @RobNapier iOS is not the only OS in the world ;-) Also, this: "int is a static size that will not optimize for different architectures." - is specifically incorrect. If we are splitting hair, let's do it correctly: in C, `int` is supposed/advised to be the fastest integer type. So if we are doing such optimization (***why?***), then it's even better to use. Now of course, ranges may be a real problem. And indeed, if there's an application that relies on an integer type being as wide as possible, then that should be `NSInteger` -- but else, that typedef hasn't any other real advantage.

Comment: Thank you all for your clarifications, I have edited my answer to be less emphatic on not using int, since that isn't the focus of the question.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Use GCD.</s>

```
static dispatch_once_t tok;
dispatch_once(&tok, ^{ memory_intensive_computation(); });
```

No, don't use GCD, I missed the point. In an instance method, you want to tie information to each *instance,* so using a static dispatch token is not appropriate. Maybe you should just stick with the "boolean flag as instance variable" approach.

Alternatively, you can initialize the `int` to a value which is known to be out of its valid range (for example, I suppose that `numberOfDays` can never be negative) and use that as a condition for performing the calculation.

Comment: `- (int)numberOfDays` is an *instance method*, and each instance has its own `_version`. So you cannot use a static dispatch_once_t. And using dispatch_once_t predicate as a member variable seems not to be allowed, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856037/can-i-declare-dispatch-once-t-predicate-as-a-member-variable-instead-of-static.

Comment: @MartinR Huh, I missed that. Surely you're right, let me think about this a bit more.

Comment: @MartinR: Yowza, I didn't know about the dynamic storage restriction either. What a bother. I wonder what that's all about.

Comment: It's because they use the actual memory location as the "I've done this" token. It needs to be something that can never change.

Comment: @RobNapier: Are you sure? Why wouldn't they store it in the actual token? Based on the comment in the header, I suspect the docs are slightly wrong on this — what it actually means is that the memory for the `dispatch_once_t` needs to be zeroed before `dispatch_once` is called, and only static and global variables are initialized that way by default in C. I'd like to hear a comment from Apple on the matter.

Comment: @RobNapier I've read the answer Martin R linked to, and that doesn't actually confirm either of the hypotheses. So we can only speculate. (But even from the speculations, the author of the answer deduced that it's not the address of the token that matters but its value.)

Comment: As far as I know, Greg Parker is from Apple, and he posted this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845164/1187415 to the above thread.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, that's nice. I didn't know we had an authoritative answer to the question.

Comment: @MartinR: Ah, thanks. How weird. I still can't imagine how the fact that the memory was non-zero before the object was initialized would ever matter to a call in an instance method, but Greg is much smarter than I am, so I'll call that settled.

Answer (score 1):

Use a NSNumber to store the int value.

```
- (int)numberOfDays
{
    if (_numberOfDays == nil) {
        // relatively memory intense calculation that works out numberOfDays:
        _numberOfDays = @(X);
    }    
    return [_numberOfDays intValue];
}
```

Comment: IMO, the NSNumber solution is by far the best approach offered here. It is simple, consistent, reliable, and fast.

Comment: Would this involve the property being an NSNumber rather than an int?

Comment: @CharlieSeligman: The instance variable _numberOfDays would be an NSNumber. The property numberOfDays is still an int.

Answer (score 1):

Add another boolean instance variable `_numberOfDaysCalculated`.
A thread-safe version would be

```
- (int)numberOfDays
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!_numberOfDaysCalculated) {
            // relatively memory intense calculation that works out numberOfDays:
            _numberOfDays = X;
            _numberOfDaysCalculated = YES;
        }
    }    
    return _numberOfDays;
}
```

Alternatively, if there is some "invalid" value of the property, you can use that
as a "not yet computed" marker. For example, if the computed value of `numberOfDays` has to be non-negative, you could initialize `_numberOfDays = -1` in the `init` method,
and then test for `if (_numberOfDays == -1)` in the lazy getter method.

Comment: Ugh, so you added the "sentinel value out of range" method as well, I see :)

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize the `_numberOfDays` in the -init with `NSNotFound` and test for that in the getter.