# class inheritance in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a parent class like this :

```
@interface SGBaseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

+ (CGFloat)defaultHeight;
...

@end
```

The `SGBaseTableViewCell` is the parent class for all my custom `UITablelViewCell`

```
@implementation SGBaseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

+ (CGFloat)defaultHeight {

    static CGFloat defaultHeight = 0.0;

     static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        SGBaseTableViewCell *cell = [[self class] newDefaultCell]; // newDefaultCell will just load the cell from a xib
        defaultHeight = cell.height;
    });
    return defaultHeight;
 }
@end
```

I would like that each custom cell will returns it's height. The problem of my code is that it will always return the same height for each cell ( will return the first cell's height).

Is there a solution that each cell will return it's height without overriding in the child class the `defaultHeight` method ?

PS : I know that i can override the `defaultHieght` method in each subclass to return the appropriate height, but i would like to know if i can do it juts in the base class ?

Tnaks

Comment: When you mean "the same height for each cell", you mean for each subclass of your cell or for each cell in a tableView (you may have cells with multi-lined labels) ?

Comment: What happens if you use `UITableViewCell *cell = [[self class] newDefaultCell];`?

Comment: @Tanguy of corse you can, in a class method self is the Class

Comment: @trojanfoe don't think that will work, the problem is with the static keyword and the dispatch_once.

Comment: What problem do you mean?

Comment: i would like that each subclass will load itself and return it's height, but with the dispatch_one, the load of cell will be called only one and will returns the height of the first call for every cell sublass

Comment: Have you tried static attribute ?
`static CGFloat classHeight = 0.0;`

and instead of `dispatch_once` use `if (classHeight == 0.0) {}`

Not sure every class will have its own classHeight.


EDIT: declare the static float above `@implementation` and not in `+ (CGFloat)defaultHeight`

Comment: @Tanguy not working. classHeight belongs to the parent class, and not each child class has it's own classHeight.

Comment: @samir, and in `@interface` ?

Comment: Same results, not working :)

Comment: My last idea, declare `static dispatch_once_t onceToken;` as a class variable for every subclass.

Comment: @Tanguy Thanks for your response, but i think that declaring disparch_one as an instance variable is not a good idea, see the answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856037/can-i-declare-dispatch-once-t-predicate-as-a-member-variable-instead-of-static/19845164#19845164

Comment: Then I have no more idea :/ Sadly I always override my `+(CGFloat)height` in cell subclass.

Comment: @Tanguy i have answered my question, if you are interested :)

Answer (score 1):

My final solution (proposed in an other forum) :

```
+ (CGFloat)defaultHeight
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSMutableDictionary *heights;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ heights = [NSMutableDictionary new]; });

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        NSString *key = NSStringFromClass(self);
        NSNumber *h = heights[key];
        if (h) return [h floatValue];
        SGBaseTableViewCell *cell = [self newDefaultCell];
        [heights setValue:@(cell.height) forKey:key];
        return cell.height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this article from RayWenderlich:
[Dynamic tableViewCell auto-layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)

It seems to be a good alternative solution and you won't have to override any method for each subclass.