# Cocoa dispatch_once per instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

How to use `dispatch_once,` so the given code is executed once, per instance lifetime.

Equivalent would be to have a property inside the object, and use it like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(..).. {

   // ...

   if (self.isDispatched == NO) {
      // ...
      self.isDispatched = YES;
   }

}
```

But I don't want to use an extra property, but the `dispatch_once_t` or similar.

Comment: Why can't you run the code in an init method or the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: because it needs to run at viewWillAppear :)

Comment: Whether you use a flag or a `dispatch_once_t`, it will have to be an instance variable (which is not the same thing as a property). And, yes, you can use a `dispatch_once_t` as an instance variable despite frequent claims to the contrary.

Comment: can you post some code as answer?

Comment: Why would you bother with using `dispatch_once` at all? It is useful for dealing with thread safety, but `viewWillAppear` method will always be called on the main thread. I think that the BOOL property is good enough in this case, according to the KISS principle. Or you can use lazily-initialized property in some circumstances (it depends on what you want to do in `viewWillAppear`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your requirements can't be satisfied. `dispatch_once` can only be used on memory that's never been written to before, and you have no way to guarantee this with instance variables. Greg Parker [says so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19845164/22927), and he's the guy who would know.

Instead, use the code in your question, but wrap it in a `@synchronized` block.

If you really want to avoid adding instance variables, you could use a separate singleton to manage a mutable set. You'd have to register instances with it and remove them on deallocation. Make sure this helper class only holds weak references; see `NSMapTable` and `NSMapTableWeakMemory`.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are curious and as an extra tip, for me this approach has been useful for this purpose:

```
class SomeVC : UIViewController {
    private var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

    public override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        dispatch_once(&token) { () -> Void in
            self.doSomethingOnce()
        }

    }
}
```

By not declaring a static var it has the expected behaviour. That being said, this is definitely NOT RECOMMENDED for any serious project, since in the Docs (as your well said) it states:

> The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope. The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic storage (including Objective-C instance variables) is undefined.

If we don't want to run into any future weird bugs and undefined behaviour I would just stick to what Apple says. But  it's still nice to play around with these things, isn't it? =)

Comment: +One for noting "The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope."