# Call a method once only for the lifetime of the object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Let's say we override `scrollViewDidScroll` method and for the first ever scroll *only*, we want to `doSomething()`

A trivial way is to implement this is to have an instance level boolean variable and toggle/check it.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
  if(!scrolled) {
   scrolled = true; 
   doSomething(); 
  }
}
```

I want a better solution that does not introduce a boolean variable `scrolled`. Something similar to `dispatch_once` but for the lifetime of the object rather than the whole process.

Is there a name for this pattern?

Comment: Why is this being down voted? It's a clear question asking a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Something similar to dispatch_once but for the lifetime of the object rather than the whole process

Unfortunately, `dispatch_once` is not safe at instance level. People who use this in Objective-C are wrong to do so. That is why `dispatch_once` is not available in Swift.

Your `if !scrolled` pattern is in fact the correct implementation (except for your use of parentheses, semicolons, and other non-Swifty stuff). It's called a *flag*.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to avoid a problem with someone else repurposing the boolean in some other area of the class, thereby messing up my implementation. E.g. say I am trying to trigger an analytics on this - someone else might be doing something related to a hidden header view or something - and is reusing the bool. The problem would show up quite late. Best way would be to avoid the boolean altogether, right?

Comment: @zakishaheen:  See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845164/1187415 from Apple engineer Greg Parker.

Comment: And some interesting discussion here https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/pull/61#issuecomment-200208084

Answer (score 2):

Since you want this done just once *per instance* of your class, using an instance variable is the proper solution. And, as you stated, it is a trivial way to do this.

If it's correct and trivial, why do you think there is a better way?

Comment: I think it adds to the 'state' of the object. I am trying to avoid it. I don't want anyone else trying to repurpose the boolean variable for some other problem thereby creating issues for my solution later.

Comment: 1) Tracking the state of the object is exactly what instance variables are for. 2) Who else are you talking about? Make it a private instance variable (or private property) and no one else will be able to "repurpose" the variable.

Comment: By someone else I mean another developer working on the same class sometime later.

Comment: That's what comments are for. And it's why variables should have good, descriptive names. You've already spent more time trying to find some mystical, much more complicated solution to a trivial problem than you will ever spend in the future due to some other developer mistakenly misusing your instance variable.