# Accessing "self" in initializing closure

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 3 the dispatch_once function was removed and the [migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) suggests to use initializing closure:

> let myGlobal = { … global contains initialization in a call to a closure … }()
>
> _ = myGlobal  // using myGlobal will invoke the initialization code only the first time it is used.

I'd like to access 'self' instance variables from within the initializing closure like so:

```
class SomeClass {
    var other = SomeOtherClass()
    
    let initialize: () = {
        // self.other - this doesn't work, complains about unresolved identifier 'self'
        // how to access self.other here?
    } ()

    func doSomething() {
        // initialize will only be called once
        initialize
    }
}
```

Why is 'self' not accessible in the closure and how can make it to be?

Comment: Using dispatch_once with an instance property to ensure a "once per instance" initialization was *always wrong,* see for example this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845164/1187415 from an Apple engineer.

Comment: So what's the correct way in Swift 3 to make sure that instance initialization code runs only once and is able to set instance variables? I can't use variations of init() in this case since the class (NSViewController) needs to run the initialization code only once but after certain point in `NSViewController` lifecycle (i.e. `viewDidAppear`). Is the answer provide by @vadian is correct (it seems to work properly) in your opinion?

Comment: Compare also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048008/call-a-method-once-only-for-the-lifetime-of-the-object-in-swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This quoted example of the Migration Guide is misleading because it's related to a global variable.

The closure of a **instance** `let` constant is called (once) immediately when the class is initialized. That's the reason why it cannot use other variables declared on the same level.

What you can do is to initialize `initialize` (the variable name is not the best one ;-) ) lazily. The closure is also called only once but – as the guide describes – *only the first time* (when) *it is used*.

```
class SomeClass {
  let other = SomeOtherClass()

  lazy var initialize : () = {
    let test = self.other
    test.doSomething()
  }()

  func doSomething() {
    // initialize will only be called once
    _ = initialize
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong in Apple's migration guide? It tells that you can use *"lazily initialized globals or static properties"* instead of dispatch_once. An *instance property* as in the question is neither a lazily initialized global nor a static property. – Using dispatch_once for this purpose was always wrong, therefore the "migration" does not apply. See also my remark at the question.

Comment: @MartinR This particular syntax is wrong. The line `_ = myGlobal` suggests that the `let myGlobal` closure is initialized lazily. Actually this line to *get* the variable is not needed at all.

Comment: The migration guide is about a *global variable* `myGlobal` to execute some code *once per application runtime*, and it cannot be applied here. There is – as far as I can see – nothing wrong in the migration guide as you claim.

Comment: @MartinR You are right but taken out of the context it's pretty misleading. I edited the answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

When an instance of the 'SomeClass' class is created, it will first create all of the variables and constants on that instance. During this time, self may not be fully initialised, because it may be halfway through setting up. Because of this, self is not available until after the initialisation step has completed.

In the example, they were talking about a global variable which has no concept of self, or a static constant on the class which also has no concept of self.

If it needs to be an instance method/variable you could:

a) make it a lazy var like

```
lazy var initialise : ()->Void = { 
    return {
        // can access self here
    }    
}()
```

which will be created the first time you call it, rather than during initialisation. Of course you lose the constant that way, and you have to store the closure which is wasteful since you're only executing it once.

b) put the code inside of an init method:

```
init() {
    // if your class doesn't have a super class, you can access self.other here. 
    // If it does have a super class (like NSObject) you must first call super.init() here to complete the initialisation. 
    // This can only be done after all other variables have been set.
}
```