# Cannot convert value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> ()'

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a class with a function that takes in closure.

```
class MyFetcher {    
    public func fetchData(searchText: String, 
                          onResponse: @escaping () -> (), 
                          showResult: @escaping (String) -> ())
    }
}
```

Calling it as below is all good

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private func fetchData(searchText: String) {
        wikipediaFetcher.fetchData(searchText: searchText,
                                   onResponse: stopIndicationAnimation,
                                   showResult: showResult)
    }

    private func stopIndicationAnimation() {
        // Do something
    }

    private func showResult(data: String) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

However when I change the closure as class parameter for `MyFetcher` as below

```
class MyFetcher {

    private let onResponse: () -> ()
    private let showResult: (String) -> ()

    init (onResponse: @escaping () -> (),
          showResult: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        self.onResponse = onResponse
        self.showResult = showResult
    }


    public func fetchData(searchText: String)
    }
}
```

Calling it as below is giving error stating 
`Cannot convert value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> ()'`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let wikipediaFetcher = WikipediaFetcher(
        onResponse: stopIndicationAnimation,  // Error is here
        showResult: showResult                // Error is here
    )

    private func stopIndicationAnimation() {
        // Do something
    }

    private func showResult(data: String) {
        // Do something
    }
```

Anything I did wrong?

Comment: I swear I've seen this before... Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556659/accessing-self-in-initializing-closure) answer your question? Basically `self` is not available in variable initialisers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring because you're initialising `wikipediaFetcher` as a property of `ViewController` before it's available `wikipediaFetcher`. Try loading it as lazy

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var wikipediaFetcher = WikipediaFetcher(
        onResponse: stopIndicationAnimation,
        showResult: showResult              
    )

    private func stopIndicationAnimation() {
        // Do something
    }

    private func showResult(data: String) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. That will do. I wonder if we could still make it `let`?

Comment: There is no option to provide `lazy let`. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#:~:text=You%20indicate%20a%20lazy%20stored,lazy%20modifier%20before%20its%20declaration.&text=You%20must%20always%20declare%20a,until%20after%20instance%20initialization%20completes.) for more details. Swift documentation is really good resource.

Comment: Thanks. I know there's no `lazy let` yet as per https://medium.com/@elye.project/lazy-comparison-of-kotlin-and-swift-e35619259923, just through if there's a smart way of working around it. Thanks for the answer. Tick as the correct one.