# Objective-C to swift translate problems

Tags: objective-c, swift, translation

I'm trying to convert this to swift:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedGameKitHelper
{
    static GameKitHelper *sharedGameKitHelper;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedGameKitHelper = [[GameKitHelper alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedGameKitHelper;
}
```

now I dont have any experience with Objective-C so I used this converter: [Objectivec2swift.com](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/) and it gave me this:

```
class func sharedGameKitHelper() -> Self {
    var sharedGameKitHelper: GameKitHelper?
    var onceToken: dispatch_once_t
    dispatch_once(onceToken, {() -> Void in
        sharedGameKitHelper = GameKitHelper()
    })
    return sharedGameKitHelper!
}
```

It gives me some error, and I have no clue what to do with it, so I would appreciate a bit of help here.

Errors:

[image: Errors]

Comment: In the sense that he *should* be using that method, yes, but there's a specific syntax question about how to use and old C API with Swift that's useful in itself.

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with old C API, need to use rare `&` operator to deal with the address-of nature of the parameter. The onceToken needs a unique value. Also you need the explicit type not `Self`.
Finally for compactness you can use trailing closure syntax and inferred function signature.

```
class GameKitHelper {
    static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 1
    class func sharedGameKitHelper() -> GameKitHelper {
        var sharedGameKitHelper: GameKitHelper?
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) { sharedGameKitHelper = GameKitHelper() }
        return sharedGameKitHelper!
    }
}
```

However, that methodology is non-idiomatic & overcomplicated. See:

http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

And in there references back to SO:

[Using a dispatch_once singleton model in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift/24147830#24147830)

Comment: It gives me an error at `dispatch_once(&oncetok...` it says: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x11)"

Comment: The dispatch_once_t variable cannot be a local variable of the function, it has to be a *static* variable (as it is in the Objectice-C code), compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845164/1187415. The correct use of dispatch_once in Swift is also demonstrated in the accepted answer of the linked-to "duplicate".

Comment: Thank you, fixed even though dup just so it's not wrong. Unless you think I should just delete this answer.

Comment: It gives me the same error though

Comment: The token must be initialized to *zero*.