# Resetting dispatch_once_t?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, locking

According to [the answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930044/possible-to-reset-state-of-dispatch-once-in-unit-test-to-make-them-run-again), you should not resetting a dispatch_once_t `isn't a good thing to do in any situation other than testing`.

Say I have a section of code that I want to make sure cannot be possibly called by multiple threads at a time (like loading data). Would this not be valid code:

```
@interface SomeClass()
{
    dispatch_once_t onceToken;
}
@end

- (void) updateMethod
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            // Do some data loading in the background.
            ...

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update the UI
                ...

                // Reset the once token. Allow the method to be called again.
                onceToken = 0;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Are there any problems with this code? Or should it be done another way?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845164/1187415: dispatch_once_t must not be an instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not attempt to use `dispatch_once` for this purpose. For this type of task you should use a serial queue or some kind of lock or semaphore, depending on your needs.

For the first choice you can do your background loading in parallel but queue the UI updates onto the main queue, which is a serial queue and UI updates should occur on the main queue.

If you require the background loading to be serial as well you queue that on a serial queue, you can create one with `dispatch_queue_create()`.

For the second choice GCD provides semaphores - `dispatch_semaphore_create()`, `dispatch_semaphore_signal()` and `dispatch_semaphore_wait()`.

In outline you:

1. Create a semaphore with a count of 1.
2. When you want to run you wait on the semaphore, your thread is blocked if the semaphore has the value 0, for > 0 the count is decremented and the thread continues
3. When the work is done you signal the semaphore - which increments it

HTH